# Finding whether $\dfrac{2^k - (2\cdot3^{n-1} + 2^{t_0}3^{n-2} + 2^{t_0+t_1}3^{n-3} .... + 2^{t_0+t_1+...+t_{n-1}})}{3^n}$ can describe all integers

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture

I was working on the Collatz conjecture(while not expecting to get anywhere) and I suspect that if it is possible to show that
$$\dfrac{2^k - (2\cdot3^{n-1} + 2^{t_0}3^{n-2} + 2^{t_0+t_1}3^{n-3} .... + 2^{t_0+t_1+...+t_{n-2}})}{3^n}$$
can represent all integers for some $k, n$ and $t_i$s, it is possible to prove the Collatz conjecture. If $t_0 \geq 1$ and $t_i > 1$ for $i>0$, $i\in \mathbb{Z}^+$

While I am aware that there is no easy way to actually prove this, I was hoping for a recommended method of approaching this problem. If requested, I will put the derivation below. However, even if the derivation is incorrect, I am still interested in whether there is a way to prove or disprove that the above can represent all integers. I have only tried one approach so far and I will put it below(even if I was unsuccessful). If this has not been a simplification, I will appreciate if that was pointed out as well.

### Proof by induction

Given 
$$z = \dfrac{2^k - (2\cdot3^{n-1} + 2^{t_0}3^{n-2} + 2^{t_0+t_1}3^{n-3} .... + 2^{t_0+t_1+...+t_{n-1}})}{3^n}$$
must satisfy $z \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. At $z=1$, as
$$1 = \dfrac{2^4-(2\cdot3 + 2^0)}{3^2} = \dfrac{9}{9} = 1$$
I here assumed that at $z=a$,
$$a = \dfrac{2^k - (2\cdot3^{n-1} + 2^{t_0}3^{n-2} + 2^{t_0+t_1}3^{n-3} .... + 2^{t_0+t_1+...+t_{n-1}})}{3^n}$$
Here, if we were to look at $z=a+1$,
$$a+1 = \dfrac{2^k + 3^n- (2\cdot3^{n-1} + 2^{t_0}3^{n-2} + 2^{t_0+t_1}3^{n-3} .... + 2^{t_0+t_1+...+t_{n-1}})}{3^n}$$
However, I was not able to think about anything from this point.

### Derivation

As it was requested, I will include a derivation. I apologize in advance for the lack of advanced mathematics. Also, since I have not went to university yet, I most likely will be lacking in my techniques of conveying the derivation or the formalness of the proof so I will apologize in advance for that too.

That said, here is the derivation. I tried to look at the number of odd cycles required to reach 1 for a particular number. For example, given an odd number $x$, 
$$ \dfrac{3x + 1}{2^{t_0}} = 1$$
then all number in the form of x will reach one in one cycle. The x is given by
$$x= \dfrac{2^{t_0}-1}{3}$$
Given two cycles, all $x$s in the form
$$\dfrac{3\dfrac{3x+1}{2^{t_0}}+1}{2^{t_1}} = \dfrac{9x + 3 + 2^{t_0}}{2^{t_0+t_1}} = 1$$
will lead to 1. The $x$ is given by
Thus given n cycles, the x that will lead to reaching 1 can be given by
$$\dfrac{3^nx + 3^{n-1} + 2^{t_0}3^{n-2}+2^{t_0+t_1}3^{n-3}...+2^{t_0 +t_1+....+t_{n-2}}}{2^{t_0+t_1+t_2....+t_{n-1}}}=1$$
Thus, when solving for $x$,
$$ x = \dfrac{2^{t_0+t_1+t_2....+t_{n-1}}-(3^{n-1} + 2^{t_0}3^{n-2}+2^{t_0+t_1}3^{n-3}...+2^{t_0 +t_1+....+t_{n-2}})}{3^n}$$
To make it account for every integer, given $n \in \mathbb{Z}$
$$ 2n+1 = \dfrac{2^{t_0+t_1+t_2....+t_{n-1}}-(3^{n-1} + 2^{t_0}3^{n-2}+2^{t_0+t_1}3^{n-3}...+2^{t_0 +t_1+....+t_{n-2}})}{3^n}$$
Thus
$$n = \dfrac{2^{t_0+t_1+t_2....+t_{n-1}}-3^n-(3^{n-1} + 2^{t_0}3^{n-2}+2^{t_0+t_1}3^{n-3}...+2^{t_0 +t_1+....+t_{n-2}})}{2\cdot3^n}=\dfrac{2^{t_0+t_1+t_2....+t_{n-1}}-(4\cdot3^{n-1} + 2^{t_0}3^{n-2}+2^{t_0+t_1}3^{n-3}...+2^{t_0 +t_1+....+t_{n-2}})}{2\cdot3^n}= \dfrac{2^{t_0+t_1+t_2....+t_{n-1}-1}-(2\cdot3^{n-1} + 2^{t_0-1}3^{n-2}+2^{t_0+t_1-1}3^{n-3}...+2^{t_0 +t_1+....+t_{n-2}-1})}{3^n}$$
Thus, when writing $k= t_0+t_1+t_2....+t_{n-1}-1$ I think it reaches the above expression.

Comment: This ansatz is well known, and there have been several attempts to prove that indeed all numbers can be represented by this structure - but with no success so far. Only with restrictions on the sequence of $t_0,t_1,...$ some progress could be made, for instance if all $t_k$ except the last would equal $1$ this leads to the "1-cycle"-problem and there has been some success with analyses on this (proof of nonexistence etc).

Comment: Ah, got it. Thank you very much! @GottfriedHelms !

Comment: I'll try another approach!

Comment: Yes, this looks equivalent to some previously-discovered representations of the Collatz problem, which are summarised fairly exhaustively by Lagarias' well-known paper. I think this equation is more revealing once you have divided the numerator throughout by $3^n$ and you can also express $t_0..$ as individual terms of a strictly increasing sequence of powers of $2$. My personal opinion is not to give up on this approach, rather I prefer to better understand what forms of such sequences are possible, and how they can be put into bijection with the integers.

Comment: ...the set of all equations of this form can be put into bijection with $\omega^{<\omega}$ and I suspect this bijection defines a bijection from $\omega^{<\omega}$ to $\Bbb Z[\frac16]\setminus0$, of which the famous graph on integers is a subgraph. But I cannot yet define the bijection to $\Bbb Z[\frac16]\setminus0$. Extending to $\Bbb Z[\frac16]$ eliminates the need to worry about which numbers have predecessors, and whether they are greater or smaller than their successor, which are the primary sources of complexity in the problem.

Comment: @RobertFrost Oh, that is quite interesting! I have not yet read that famous paper and I do not understand the second portion completely yet I will read it and I will give it another try!  I have tried another approach yet while I think I made a bit of progress, I was actually thinking about finding another method like the one here. Thank you!

Comment: I don't suppose you could put your derivation so I can compare with mine? Thanks.

Comment: @Roskiller Sure! I'll put it in in just a moment.