# Can any integer, not a multiple of three, be represented as $n = \sum_{i=0}^{a-1} 3^i \times 2^{b_i}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, collatz-conjecture

This question has some relevance to the Collatz conjecture. It was originally based on trying to represent a number like this: [Finding whether $\dfrac{2^k - (2\cdot3^{n-1} + 2^{t_0}3^{n-2} + 2^{t_0+t_1}3^{n-3} .... + 2^{t_0+t_1+...+t_{n-1}})}{3^n}$ can describe all integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2860934/finding-whether-dfrac2k-2-cdot3n-1-2t-03n-2-2t-0t-13n?noredirect=1#comment6141100_2860934)

However, I generalised that and tried to ask a simpler question instead, now this is simply out of curiosity rather than anything useful, as in often the case with the Collatz conjecture.

Is it possible to represent a number that is not divisible by three as:
$$n = \sum_{i=0}^{a-1} 3^i \times 2^{b_i}$$
$$n, a, b_i \in \Bbb{Z^+_0}$$
Where $b_i$ is some arbitrary integer such that $b_{i+1} \leq b_i$

For example, $13=1+3+9$.

EDIT: My original question asked what happened with these conditions: 
 $$n, a, b_i \in \Bbb{Z^+}$$
$$b_{i+1} < b_i$$
(Notice the subtle differences in specifications.) Under these above conditions, some numbers cannot be represented, like $13$. What are some characteristics of numbers that **cannot** be represented like this?

Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If $a=1$ and $b_i>0$ is not satisfied, I dont think so.

Comment: This turned out to be a lot more interesting than it first appeared. Thanks!

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy Can you make it rigorous?

Comment: And your "not a multiple of three" is a red herring, since multiples of 3 can clearly be represented in this form if non-multiples can.

Comment: @MJD How so? A number congruent to 0 mod 3 cannot be represented like this as expanding out this sum will show an extra power of 2 without a power of 3, meaning this is 1 or 2 mod 3.

Comment: The answer is yes, but I can't write it up until I get home later. Summary: Every even number is represented with $b_i>0$, so we can represent $2n$ if and only if we can also represent $n$. Now say $n$ is in $[3^k..3^{k+1}-1]$ and is odd. Then represent $n$ as $3^k+2n'$, and get the representation of $2n'$ from the representation of $n'$, which is already representable by the same method. (Induction argument.) Choosing a random example, $12467= 6561+2\cdot 2187+4\cdot243+16\cdot 27+1 28\cdot 1$.

Comment: In your example, the exponents are not strictly increasing by one. You have $3^0=1$ followed by $3^3 = 27$. Due to this application in the collatz conjecture the exponents must only increase by one. This is indicated by the use of $3^i$.

Comment: I also did not ever doubt that $1 = 2^0$ and hence a power of two.

Comment: I see I misunderstood your conditions. Sorry, I will look into it more later on.  How is it possible to represent 13 in your form?

Comment: I have tried to do this already, but it does not seem all too easy to fix up, as all exponents must be increasing, positive, and always must follow the rules I have indictated. The only freedom you have is the choice of $a$ and $b_i$

Comment: That is a good point, I do not believe $13$ can be represented, I shall generalize the question to allow $b_i=b_{i+1}$

Comment: How is this representation of $13$ legal?  As you pointed out, the $1$ term is not allowed because it has $b_0 = 0$, but you required $b_i > 0$.  If all the $b_i$ are required to be positive, obviously no odd number can be represented.

Comment: No because you can add a power of three to make it odd, and I have updated the question to allow for this representation of $13$ due to $b_i \in \Bbb{Z^+_0}$

Comment: Have you thought about how to represent this as a string of digits? e.g., balanced ternary can use 2 for $-1$.

Comment: It might be helpful if you gave some reason to believe that the relation should hold, and/or if you expounded a little on the connection to the Collatz Conjecture. If the connection is something like "my relation implies Collatz with a single trivial step", then one might reasonably suspect that your relation isn't particularly-easy to establish.

Comment: Good idea @RobertSoupe, I had not thought of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I deduced the same thing when study the Collatz conjecture, here is the proof without the restrictions and some stuff related.*

Let $G_n = \{m \in \mathbb{N} \,|\,\gcd(m,n) = 1\}$

We can do this for all $G_n$, for example $n = 2$, but we only interested in $n = 3$.

**Lemma:**
For all $n \in G_3$, exists $a \in \mathbb{Z} : 0 \le a$ such that:

1. $n = 2^a \hspace{5pt} (\text{mod } 3)$
2. $n \neq 2^a \hspace{5pt} (\text{mod } 9)$

**Proof:**
Without loss of generality, we use this table:

```
      +---+---+---+---+----+----+
      | 1 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 16 | 32 |
+-----+---+---+---+---+----+----+
|Mod 3| 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1  | 2  |
+-----+---+---+---+---+----+----+
|Mod 9| 1 | 2 | 4 | 8 | 7  | 5  |
+-----+---+---+---+---+----+----+
```

From the table:

1. For all $n \in G_3$, exists $a$ such that $n = 2^a\ (\text{mod }3)$.
2. For all $n \in G_3$, exists $a$ such that $n = 2^a\ (\text{mod }9)$.
3. By contradiction, suppose that for all $a$ we have $n = 2^a\ (\text{mod }3)$ and $n = 2^a\ (\text{mod }9)$.

   By the table, exists $a'$ such that $2^a = 2^{a'}\ (\text{mod }3)$ and $2^{a} \neq 2^{a'}\ (\text{mod }9)$.

   Then, $n = 2^{a'}\ (\text{mod }3)$ and $n \neq 2^{a'}\ (\text{mod }9)$.

Finally, by contradiction, exists $a$.

**Corollary:** For all $n \in G_3$, exists $a \in \mathbb{Z} : 0 \le a$ and $k \in G_3$ such that $n = 2^a + 3k$.

**Notation:** If a number $n$ can be represented in this form, for some $l \in \mathbb{Z} : 0 \le l$:
$$ n = 2^{\alpha_0} + 2^{\alpha_1}\,3^{1} + 2^{\alpha_2} + ... + 2^{\alpha_{l}}\,3^{l} $$
such that $\alpha_i \in \mathbb{Z} : \alpha_i \ge 0$ for $i = 1, ..., l$.

Then, we said that n can be represented in a $l$-canonical form and if exists $l \in \mathbb{Z} : 0 \le l$ such that n is a $l$-canonical form then we said n can be represented in the canonical form.

**Theorem:** Every number in $G_3$ can be represented in the canonical form.

**Proof:** We prove by induction that $n$ can be represented in that form, for all $n \in G_3$.

**Base case:**

You can find a expression for all $n \in G_3 : n \le 9$.

**Inductive case:**

Suppose this is holds for all $k \in G_3 : k < n$:

By the **corollary**, exists $a$ and $k \in G_3$ such that $n = 2^a + 3 k$.
Because $k < n$, $k = 2^{\alpha_0} + 2^{\alpha_1}\,3 + ... + 2^{\alpha_i}\,3^i$.

Finally, because $n = 2^{a} + 3\,(2^{\alpha_0} + 2^{\alpha_1}\,3 + ... + 2^{\alpha_i}\,3^i)$, every number in $G_3$ can be represented in the canonical form.

**Notation:** If $n \in G_3$ can be represented in a $0$-canonical form, we said $n$ can be represented in the canonical principal form.

**Notation:** If $m$ can be represented in a $l$-canonical form and $n = m + 3^{l + 1}\,t$ then we said $t$ is in the tail of $n$, with $n,m,t \in G_3$.

**The Collatz conjecture implies that every number in $G_3$ is in the tail of some canonical principal form.**

**Conjecture:** If $n \in G_3$ can be represented in a $a$-canonical form and $b$-canonical form, for $a \le b$, then $n$ can be represented in a $l$-canonical form, for all $l \in \mathbb{Z} : a \le l \le b$.

Comment: Very nice proof, however one slight snag. You say that $2^a +3(2^{\alpha_0}+...+2^{\alpha_i}3^i) = n$, however you have not assured that $a\geq \alpha_i$. Despite this, this proof could be extended to cover the aforementioned case?

Comment: Exactly i not prove that because i did not know how, my answer was only a help. But now i know how (I might edit today or tomorrow). This is the idea to prove that $\alpha_0 \ge a$. Suppose, without loss of generality, that $\alpha_0 = a + 1$ and a is the maximum (i.e. not exists $k \in G_3$, for $a + 2$, such that $n = 2^{a+2} + 3k$); Then, $n = 2^a + 2^{a+1}\,3 + 3^2\,k'$ for some $k' \in G_3$. This implies that exists $k \in G_3$ such that $n = 2^a(1+3*2) + 3^2\,k = 2^a(2^2 + 3) + 3^2\,k' = 2^{a+2} + 3k$. Then, by contradiction, $\alpha_0 \le a$. Finally, by induction, $a \ge \alpha_i$.

Answer (score 0):

*This is only a comment, but too long for the comment box*

Since your $b$'s are organized as equal or decreasing one can define "layers" of equal $b$ and sum the terms with equal $2^b$ and decreasing powers of $3$ up. That would give something like
$$ n = 2^{b_1}\left( {3^{A_1} -1 \over 3-1 }\right) + 2^{b_2}\left( {3^{A_2} -1 \over 3-1 } \right) + ... + 2^{b_m}\left( {3^{A_m} -1 \over 3-1 } \right)$$
and can even be expressed more compact like this form
$$ n = 2^{b_1}\left( {3^{A_1} -1 \over 3-1 }+ 2^{b_2}\left( {3^{A_2} -1 \over 3-1 }  + ... + 2^{b_m}\left( {3^{A_m} -1 \over 3-1 } \right)\right)\right) $$
(the indexes $A_k$ and $b_k$ are used only as models, not actual indices here).
From this the question can then also be written in base-3 representation
$$ n=2^{b_1} \cdot 111111...1_3 + 2^{b_2} \cdot 111...1_3 + ...$$
or so. Perhaps looking at such representations would easier give an idea whether any number $n$ can be expressed in such a form.